# Table reference for VLOOKUP VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm trying to use a table as reference for my VLOOKUP function using VBA, but it doesn't seem to work. Could somebody help me? My guess is that I'm not calling the tables properly.

Some info:

1. Table_3 and Table1 are set tables
2. Both of them are not fixed (data is added to it)

```
Range("Table_3[Status]") = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("Table_3[Part_Number]"), Range("Table1[[#All];[Part Number]:[Status]]"), 3, False)
```

Comment: I don't think you can use VLOOKUP like that.  the first argument should be a value, not a range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim tbl1 As ListObject, tbl3 As ListObject

    'Set you sheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Set tables
        Set tbl1 = .ListObjects("Table1")
        Set tbl3 = .ListObjects("Table_3")
        tbl3.ListColumns("Status").DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP([Part Number],Table1[#All],3,FALSE)"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I guess I didn't express myself pretty well.

If I were to do this using cells from a worksheet, I would just fill the table column ("Table_3[Stock Qty]") with this formula

`=VLOOKUP(Table_3[Part Number];Table1[[Part Number]:[Stock Qty]];3;0)`

Comment: see the new answer

Comment: Wow, nice!
I wouldn't know how to do it! I'll try that!

Comment: i ll wait for your feedback

Comment: I got a MsgBox with "Application-defined or object-defined error"
Somehow it's not being able to understand the formula

Comment: At the "tbl3.ListColumns("Status").DataBody[...]" line

Comment: make sure that the table 3 has a column named "Status"

Comment: It worked if I move the Part Number column to the first column of the table
(I know vlookup uses the first column, but my array would not include all table, just 3 columns from it)

Edit:
That's why at first I tried using `"Table1[[#All];[Part Number]:[Status]]"` instead of just `Table1[#All]`
But it didn't work

Comment: I don't get it.
If I manually insert to Table_3 (Status) Column

`"=VLOOKUP([Part Number];Table1[[#All];[Part Number]:[Status]];3;FALSE)"`
It works.

If try to insert it using vba, it doesn't work

Comment: could you please upload an image of your tables?

Comment: Sorry about the delay.
I decided to solve this using to while loops instead... ):